# How to place a treeview item above ite root in wpf

Tags: wpf, treeview, alignment

the question is I have a treeview with only one root(US).I am taking two treeviewitems(Dallas & NewYork), so that when I click on Root I get like this

US
-Dallas
-NewYork

now the requirement  I have is  to get one of the treeviewitems above the root(when I am clicking it) like this

-Dallas
US
-NewYork

Any idea how to do this??? please help

Comment: Not sure I follow this question, For your requirement do you want "Dallas" as a new top-level node in the `TreeView` when clicked? If so just modify your `ItemSource` accordingly in having 2 top level nodes.

Comment: yep I got it thanks Viv